# How to read an image with PHP?

Tags: php, image

i know that

```
$localfile = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
```

will get the image given that the POST method was used. I am trying to read an image which is in the same directory as my code. How do i read it and assign it to a variable like the one above?

Comment: Your example just reads the filename, not the contents of the image. What is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 15):

The code you posted will not read the image data, but rather its filename. If you need to retrieve an image in the same directory, you can retrieve its contents with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), which can be used to directly output it to the browser:

```
$im = file_get_contents("./image.jpeg");
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $im;
```

Otherwise, you can use [the GD library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) to read in the image data for further image processing:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("./image.jpeg");
if ($im) {
  // do other stuff...
  // Output the result
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  imagejpeg($im);
}
```

Finally, if you *don't know* the filename of the image you need (though if it's in the same location as your code, you should), you can use a `glob()` to find all the jpegs, for example:

```
$jpegs = glob("./*.jpg");
foreach ($jpegs as $jpg) {
  // print the filename
  echo $jpg;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between these two?       $localfile = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];
      $filename = $_FILES['media']['name'];

Comment: One is the filename of the file stored on your server (tmp_name), the other was the original filename on the client computer that uploaded the file (name).

Comment: @Mozammil `name` points to the files original name as uploaded by the user.  `tmp_name` is a filename assigned by PHP in temporary space, which points to the actual file data. It only exists until the script terminates, then `tmp_name` is no longer valid.

Comment: @Mozammil No, I have no experience with SimpleImage

Comment: But say i have a file named image.jpg which is stored in my server, same directory. How do i get its filename, the same as $localfile = $_FILES['media']['tmp_name'];

Comment: @Mozammil my first or third example above. If you know the filename, you just store it in a variable `$filename = "./image.jpg";` if you don' tknow the filename, retrieve it with `glob()`

Comment: and if i echo $localfile what would it output?

Comment: @Mozammil It would output whatever you put into it. If it holds a filename, it will output a filename, not the file data. If you call the file in with `file_get_contents()` echoing it out will output the actual binary file data.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read an image and then render it as an image

```
$image="path-to-your-image"; //this can also be a url
$filename = basename($image);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));
switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
    default:
}

header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
$image = file_get_contents($image);
echo $image;
```

If your path is a url, and it is using https:// protocol then you might want to change the protocol to http

[Working fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8qpe-icz4)

Comment: Determining the file's MIME type by file's extension is not a good practice, i think. Wouldn't it be better if it checked the file's MIME type using [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)?