# How to protect files with .htaccess and a login page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hosting on my servers few files (like photos, music etc) that I don't want to be public. So I build a PHP form that asks for OTP, and if the code is correct, it shows "OK". It's not hard to prohibit the access to a PHP file, but how can I do it to any other file type?

For example, I want that when user enters to:

```
www.example.net/private.png
```

The `.htaccess` will go to:

```
www.example.net/access.php
```

Without the user knowing it, like AJAX.

If the file returns `true`, it shows the user the content in the `www.example.net/private.png`. if it returns him `false`, it'll show him the form in this URL:

```
www.example.net/login.php?url=private.png
```

After successful login, the PHP will redirect him to:

```
www.example.net/private.png
```

Again. Than all the process again, but now, because he is already logged in, `www.example.net/access.php` will return him `true`.

What should be written in the `.htaccess` file to do it?

Comment: what is stopping you from doing this with just PHP? save the images to a non-accessible folder or just make that folder deny all access and server all the images from your PHP file from an accessible folder. [How to read an image with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034255/how-to-read-an-image-with-php)

Comment: @Prix someone edited the post. The image is just an a example, it can be a css file, a movie etc...

Comment: You omitted the fact it could be any kind of file, the edit was to improve the readability of your question as there was nothing changed on it that was not already mentioned there. You can use PHP to anything not just image.

Comment: @Prix so how do it do a redirect to `access.php?path=THEPATH` using HTACCESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guard file access using PHP, put the files in a private directory not directly accessible to the web.

Create a PHP script to allow user login

#### `login.php`

```
<?PHP
session_start();

// { Write your own code to authenticate the user }

echo "<h1>Logged in</h1>";

// set this after user logs in successfully
$_SESSION['access_allowed'] = true;

?>
```

Create another PHP script to check if the user is logged in. If the user is logged in, read the requested file from your private directory and push it to the browser.

#### `guard.php`

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['access_allowed'])){
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized"); // or redirect to the login page
    exit;
}

$private_dir = "/home/tester/guarded";
$filename = $private_dir.$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

if(!file_exists($filename)) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}

// $mime_type = "application/octet-stream";

// Finding MIME type using Fileinfo extension
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);

header('Content-Type: '.$mime_type);
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
exit;
?>
```

When a logged user requests **www.youserver.com/guard.php/image/secret.jpg** he/she will be sent the image file: **/home/tester/guarded/image/secret.jpg**

### Further Changes

Add this to your .htaccess file (make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in your Apache web server)

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(video|music|image)/(.*)$ guard.php/$1/$2
```

If your music files are located in the `music` directory inside your private directory, only logged-in users can access song.mp3 at **http://www.yourserver.com/music/song.mp3**

Videos and images can be accessed similarly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now only the `HTACCESS` file left. how do it do a redirect from `www.example.net/music/song.mp3` to `www.example.net/guard.php`, without changing the URL??

Comment: I have added a `Further Changes` section to answer your question.

Comment: the problem is that I want it to affect on any file and subfolder in the folder where I put the htaccess file. That means it can be (the htaccess is in hidden) `www.example.net/private/hidden/me.png`, and it can be `www.example.net/private/hidden/germany/2014/berlin/panoramas/brows.html`. The view file located in the same folder as the htaccess - `hidden`.

Comment: You will also be able to access files place inside folders inside folders inside folders.... For example if you have placed a file at /home/tester/guarded/image/germany/2014/berlin/panoramas/brows.html you can access it at www.yourserver.com/image/germany/2014/berlin/panoramas/brows.html

Comment: The name `image`,`video`,`music` are just examples.. it can be anything. You can put all your guarded files in just one private folder named `hidden` ($private_dir = "/home/tester/hidden") and change the .htaccess to: RewriteRule ^hidden/(.*)$ guard.php/$1 The URL will be: www.example.net/hidden/germany/2014/berlin/panoramas/brows.html

Comment: FYI - I just had an issue where `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` did not exist.  I had to modify the code to use `$_GET['PATH_INFO']` and thus the rewrite rule to `RewriteRule ^(video|music|image)/(.*)$ guard.php?PATH_INFO=/$1/$2`  The error received was "ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH" in the browser